# Wait, is that variable ever assigned?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, meta-programming, antlr, rubberduck

One of the inspections we wanted to implement in [Rubberduck](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/master/README.md) for the [next release](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22Version+1.2%22), is one that finds all unassigned variables in a VBA project.

[image: unassigned module-scoped variable appears as an "error" in the Code Inspections window]

Implementing this inspection has been ...complicated (it's the most complex inspection in the Rubberduck code base so far). Here's the code:

```
public class VariableNotAssignedInspection : IInspection
{
    public VariableNotAssignedInspection()
    {
        Severity = CodeInspectionSeverity.Error;
    }

    public string Name { get { return InspectionNames.VariableNotAssigned; } }
    public CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get { return CodeInspectionType.CodeQualityIssues; } }
    public CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults(IEnumerable<VBComponentParseResult> parseResult)
    {
        var parseResults = parseResult.ToList();

        // publics & globals delared at module-scope in standard modules:
        var globals = 
            parseResults.Select(result => 
                            new 
                            { 
                                Name = result.QualifiedName, 
                                Globals = result.ParseTree.GetContexts<DeclarationSectionListener, ParserRuleContext>(new DeclarationSectionListener())
                                                          .OfType<VisualBasic6Parser.VariableStmtContext>()
                                                          .Where(context => 
                                                              context.visibility() != null && 
                                                              context.visibility().GetText() != Tokens.Private)
                                                          .SelectMany(context => context.variableListStmt().variableSubStmt()
                                                                                .Select(variable => variable.ambiguousIdentifier()))
                            })
                         .SelectMany(module => module.Globals.Select(global => 
                            new
                            {
                                Name = module.Name,
                                Global = global
                            })).ToList();

        var assignedGlobals = new List<VisualBasic6Parser.AmbiguousIdentifierContext>();
        var unassignedDeclarations = new List<CodeInspectionResultBase>();

        foreach (var result in parseResults)
        {
            // module-scoped in this module:
            var declarations = result.ParseTree.GetContexts<DeclarationSectionListener, ParserRuleContext>(new DeclarationSectionListener())
                                     .OfType<VisualBasic6Parser.VariableSubStmtContext>()
                                     .Where(variable => globals.All(global => global.Global.GetText() != variable.GetText()))
                                     .ToList();
            var procedures = result.ParseTree.GetContexts<ProcedureListener, ParserRuleContext>(new ProcedureListener()).ToList();

            // fetch & scope all assignments:
            var assignments = procedures.SelectMany(
                procedure => procedure.GetContexts<VariableAssignmentListener, VisualBasic6Parser.AmbiguousIdentifierContext>(new VariableAssignmentListener())
                                     .Select(context => new
                                         {
                                             Scope = new QualifiedMemberName(result.QualifiedName, ((dynamic)procedure).ambiguousIdentifier().GetText()),
                                             Name = context.GetText()
                                         }));

            // fetch & scope all procedure-scoped declarations:
            var locals = procedures.SelectMany(
                procedure => procedure.GetContexts<DeclarationListener, ParserRuleContext>(new DeclarationListener())
                                      .OfType<VisualBasic6Parser.VariableSubStmtContext>()
                                      .Select(context => new
                                         {
                                             Context = context,
                                             Scope = new QualifiedMemberName(result.QualifiedName, ((dynamic)procedure).ambiguousIdentifier().GetText()),
                                             Name = context.ambiguousIdentifier().GetText()
                                         }));

            // identify unassigned module-scoped declarations:
            unassignedDeclarations.AddRange(
                declarations.Select(d => d.ambiguousIdentifier())
                            .Where(d => globals.All(g => g.Global.GetText() != d.GetText()) 
                                    && assignments.All(a => a.Name != d.GetText()))
                            .Select(identifier => new VariableNotAssignedInspetionResult(Name, Severity, identifier, result.QualifiedName)));

            // identify unassigned procedure-scoped declarations:
            unassignedDeclarations.AddRange(
                locals.Where(local => assignments.All(a => (a.Scope.MemberName + a.Name) != (local.Scope.MemberName + local.Name)))
                      .Select(identifier => new VariableNotAssignedInspetionResult(Name, Severity, identifier.Context.ambiguousIdentifier(), result.QualifiedName)));

            // identify globals assigned in this module:
            assignedGlobals.AddRange(globals.Where(global => assignments.Any(a => a.Name == global.Global.GetText()))
                                            .Select(global => global.Global));
        }

        // identify unassigned globals:
        var assignedIdentifiers = assignedGlobals.Select(assigned => assigned.GetText());
        var unassignedGlobals = globals.Where(global => !assignedIdentifiers.Contains(global.Global.GetText()))
                                       .Select(identifier => new VariableNotAssignedInspetionResult(Name, Severity, identifier.Global, identifier.Name));
        unassignedDeclarations.AddRange(unassignedGlobals);

        return unassignedDeclarations;
    }
}
```

Could this be simplified?

The `VariableNotAssignedInspectionResult` class is much simpler - it simply removes the unassigned variable declaration:

```
public class VariableNotAssignedInspetionResult : CodeInspectionResultBase
{
    public VariableNotAssignedInspetionResult(string inspection, CodeInspectionSeverity type,
        ParserRuleContext context, QualifiedModuleName qualifiedName)
        : base(inspection, type, qualifiedName, context)
    {
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes()
    {
        return
            new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>
            {
                {"Remove unused variable", RemoveVariableDeclaration}
            };
    }

    private void RemoveVariableDeclaration(VBE vbe)
    {
        var module = vbe.FindCodeModules(QualifiedName).First();
        var selection = QualifiedSelection.Selection;

        var originalCodeLines = module.get_Lines(selection.StartLine, selection.LineCount)
            .Replace("\r\n", " ")
            .Replace("_", string.Empty);

        var originalInstruction = Context.GetText();
        module.DeleteLines(selection.StartLine, selection.LineCount);

        var newInstruction = string.Empty;
        var newCodeLines = string.IsNullOrEmpty(newInstruction)
            ? string.Empty
            : originalCodeLines.Replace(originalInstruction, newInstruction);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newCodeLines))
        {
            module.InsertLines(selection.StartLine, newCodeLines);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll have to change it a bit - an *unassigned* variable isn't necessarily *unused*, and removing its declaration can actually make the code uncompilable (with `Option Explicit` specified) if the *unassigned* variable is actually *used* anyway. But the crux is there, and works as intended - at least it seems to, in all cases I've tested.

---

Rubberduck uses reflection to find all implementations of the `IInspection` interface; this means the above code (`IInspection` and `CodeInspectionResultBase` implementations) is all I needed to get a working brand new inspection. Below is the code that actually performs all inspections - the order in which inspection results come in isn't important, so I'm creating a `Task` for each one of them:

```
    private void Refresh()
    {
        var code = (_parser.Parse(VBE.ActiveVBProject)).ToList();

        var results = new ConcurrentBag<CodeInspectionResultBase>();
        var inspections = _inspections.Where(inspection => inspection.Severity != CodeInspectionSeverity.DoNotShow)
            .Select(inspection =>
                new Task(() =>
                {
                    var result = inspection.GetInspectionResults(code);
                    foreach (var inspectionResult in result)
                    {
                        results.Add(inspectionResult);
                    }
                })).ToArray();

        foreach (var inspection in inspections)
        {
            inspection.Start();
        }

        Task.WaitAll(inspections);

        _results = results.ToList();
        Control.SetContent(_results.Select(item => new CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem(item)).OrderBy(item => item.Component).ThenBy(item => item.Line));
    }
```

Is this an efficient approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't address your actually question (simplifying the logic/implementation), but I feel like it's important.

For the sake of readability, I would recommend replacing some of the nested lambdas with a function reference to a named methods. The assignment to `globals` in the first section of code has 5 levels of indentation. That is a bit much for an assignment statement. Looking at the lambda passed to the first `Select()` is scary. If I had more context with the code, it might not seem that daunting. But at first glance, there is a lot going on.

The way the code is now, I feel like I would have to dive in and understand all the details just to understand the basic steps it is taking. The first time I read through code, I don't care about the small implementation details. A well named method is a great way to extract away the details and convey your intent. Then, when I have a higher level understanding, then I can dive into the things that caught my eye as potential issues. Requiring this much up-front commitment is likely hindering your actual question from being looked into.

A simple example from your code:

```
.Where(context =>
       context.visibility() != null &&
       context.visibility().GetText() != Tokens.Private)
```

I just want to know you are filtering for non-private tokens, not how you check for one.

```
.Where(IsNonPrivateToken)
```

This takes the pressure of the reader as the LINQ statement reads more like a sentence than code.

Doing this will also help with the excessive indentation. The majority of that first `Select()` lambda requires horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

Extract a whole class out of this code, call it `IdentifierUsageInspector`, and then have your *identifier usage* inspections use that class.

Keep the methods simple, straightforward, and to the point, and the result will be (much) cleaner code.

I boiled the `GetInspectionResults` implementation down to this:

```
public IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults(IEnumerable<VBComponentParseResult> parseResult)
{
    var inspector = new IdentifierUsageInspector(parseResult);
    var issues = inspector.UnassignedGlobals()
          .Union(inspector.UnassignedFields())
          .Union(inspector.UnassignedLocals());

    foreach (var issue in issues)
    {
        yield return new VariableNotAssignedInspectionResult(Name, Severity, issue.Context, issue.QualifiedName);
    }
}
```

I don't think it gets much simpler than that! And now all inspections that need to know what's unassigned where and in which scope, can reuse the extracted code.